# Using of 2 while to get this

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I have 2 questions:

1: How can get the result below using two while loops?

```
2
4 2
6 4 2
8 6 4 2
10 8 6 4 2
12 10 8 6 4 2
14 12 10 8 6 4 2
16 14 12 10 8 6 4 2
```

2: How would I do it using two for loops?

Comment: Do you know how a while loop works? Do you know how a for loop works? Do you know how to print something? If yes, what's stopping you? If no, go read a basic tutorial.

Comment: I am just trying to learn the basics. You can also just disregard the questions that are too low level for you ;)

Comment: It does not look like you are trying to learn anything though, you don't seem to have tried anything yourself.

Comment: I agree with @timgeb. Stack Overflow is for issues that you have already researched and attempted yourself. Try to write a program that does this, and if you get stuck, post the code that you wrote, asking for help with a specific bug. The biggest part of learning to code is writing some stuff yourself and debugging it. You learn so much more from your own trial and error than looking through someone else's solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It's basic algorithm, you should find some tutorials if you don't know loops in Java

With while:

```
int i = 2;
while (i <= 16) {
    int j = i;
    while (j > 0) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
        j -= 2;
    }
    System.out.println();
    i += 2;
}
```

With for:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 16; i += 2) {
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j -= 2) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use code (two for loops example):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for(int k = (i+1); k > 0; --k) {
      System.out.print(k*2+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

and two while loops:

```
int i = 0, j;
while(i < 8) {
  j = (i+1);
  while(j > 0) {
    System.out.print(j*2+" ");
    j--;
  }
  System.out.println();
  i++;
}
```

for and while loops are similar, they are differ only by construction.